# Laravel 5 Intervention create directory uploading image - NotWritableException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, upload, intervention

I am trying to upload and resize an image in Laravel 5 and the Intervention library.

My code in the Controller is this:

```
 // Upload img
    if ($req->hasFile('img')) {
        // Original
        $image = Image::make(Input::file('img'));
        // Mid sized
        $image_mid = $image->fit(500,500, function($constraint) {
            $constraint->upsize();
        });
        // Thumbnail
        $image_thumb = $image->fit(100,100, function($constraint) {
            $constraint->upsize();
        });
        // Path
        $path = public_path('upload/artists/' . $id . '/profile/');
        if (!File::exists($path)) {
            File::makeDirectory($path . 'original', 0775, true, true);
            File::makeDirectory($path . 'midsize', 0775, true, true);
            File::makeDirectory($path . 'thumb', 0775, true, true);
        }
        // Save images
        $image->save($path . 'original/' . $imgName);
        $image_mid->save($path . 'midsize/' . $imgName);
        $image_thumb->save($path . 'thumb/' . $imgName);
    }
```

I am already trying to create de directories before moving the image, but it still gives me the same error, that I don't have permissions to move the image to that folder "NotWritableException".

Before using Intervention library, I was moving the image with the ->move() method and it was creating the directory if necessary.

I would really appreciate some help..
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you need to make the directory writable by the webserver i.e `chmod -R +w <directory>`, notice that this should be done on the parent directory in which the folders will be created. Check if the `upload/artists/' . $id . '/profile/` is writable. Perhaps these directories are created without the correct permissions.

Comment: @cyclone Thanks for the answer, but I have already changed the ownership to user:www-data and mod to 777.

Comment: Then perhaps you're trying to write to an invalid path? Can you try to use an absolute path to your upload directory and see if this works?